# Return nonzero for LdaMallet

Tags: gensim, lda, mallet

My coworker and I have the exact same code, using the same libraries, but yet his code works and mine doesn't. We've gotten stuck trying to figure out what is wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The code and error are below.

**Code:**

```
import os
os.environ.update({'MALLET_HOME':r'C:...\\mallet-2.0.8/'})
mallet_path = 'C:...\\mallet-2.0.8\\bin\\mallet' 
ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=10, id2word=id2word)
```

**Output and Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-6122457c60e1> in <module>
----> 1 ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=10, id2word=id2word)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\wrappers\ldamallet.py in __init__(self, mallet_path, corpus, num_topics, alpha, id2word, workers, prefix, optimize_interval, iterations, topic_threshold, random_seed)
    129         self.random_seed = random_seed
    130         if corpus is not None:
--> 131             self.train(corpus)
    132 
    133     def finferencer(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\wrappers\ldamallet.py in train(self, corpus)
    270 
    271         """
--> 272         self.convert_input(corpus, infer=False)
    273         cmd = self.mallet_path + ' train-topics --input %s --num-topics %s  --alpha %s --optimize-interval %s '\
    274             '--num-threads %s --output-state %s --output-doc-topics %s --output-topic-keys %s '\

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\wrappers\ldamallet.py in convert_input(self, corpus, infer, serialize_corpus)
    259             cmd = cmd % (self.fcorpustxt(), self.fcorpusmallet())
    260         logger.info("converting temporary corpus to MALLET format with %s", cmd)
--> 261         check_output(args=cmd, shell=True)
    262 
    263     def train(self, corpus):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gensim\utils.py in check_output(stdout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
   1916             error = subprocess.CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
   1917             error.output = output
-> 1918             raise error
   1919         return output
   1920     except KeyboardInterrupt:

CalledProcessError: Command 'C:\mallet-2.0.8\bin\mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input C:\Users\CST~1.JEO\AppData\Local\Temp\84f7e0_corpus.txt --output C:\Users\CST~1.JEO\AppData\Local\Temp\84f7e0_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Comment: I would try copying the command string (the part inside single quotes) from the last line and try running it by itself in a command window.

Comment: @DavidMimno The command string seems to execute just fine in the command window.

Comment: Is that the same command-window from which you're running your Python code? What if you run the Python code from that same command-window where the standalone command-line succeeds? (If its the same machine, and the same command succeeds in one shell, but not another, the failing context likely lacks some necessary state – env vars? effective user? relative paths? free memory? etc – that the succeeding context has.)